# Assertion with Side Effects

Tags: c++

In my happy debugging session today, I realized that the cause of a segmentation fault was more or less the following:

```
assert(functionWithSideEffect());
doSomethingWhichSegfaultsUnlessSideEffectHappens();
```

I'm very aware that you should never do something like this and I obviously fixed the code but I'm still confused why the segmentation fault happened while having tested with a debug executable, i.e. without defining NDEBUG.

*Shouldn't the function in the argument of the assertion be executed in this case?*

Comment: When you stepped through this code using your debugger, was the `functionWithSideEffect` called?

Comment: There is a potential that someone/something/somewhere, has redefined the assert macro, perhaps? [Or added `#define NDEBUG` for a particular section of code]. Or, if `functionWithSideEffects` is not a function, but for example a macro, with some condition, so the short-circuiting of the condition in the `if (!x) ...` type thing in `assert`. Study the pre-processed output!